# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'nets' for object detection api

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, google-colaboratory, object-detection-api

I am trying to train TF object detection model on colab and I have added 'slim' to $PYTHONPATH

> ```
> ['/env/python',
>  '/content/gdrive/My\\ Drive/Real_Traffic_Vehicle_Detector/models/research',
>  '/content/gdrive/My\\ Drive/Real_Traffic_Vehicle_Detector/models/research/slim',
> '/content/gdrive/My\\Drive/Real_Traffic_Vehicle_Detector/models/research/object_detection',
> ```

but even then when I try to run train.py file it shows error that no module named 'nets'. can anyone help me out?

> WARNING:tensorflow: The TensorFlow contrib module will not be included
>   in TensorFlow 2.0. For more information, please see:   *
>   https://github.com/tensorflow/community/blob/master/rfcs/20180907-contrib-sunset.md
>   * https://github.com/tensorflow/addons   * https://github.com/tensorflow/io (for I/O related ops) If you depend
>   on functionality not listed there, please file an issue.
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "train.py", line 52, in
>   
>       from object_detection.builders import model_builder   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/object_detection/builders/model_builder.py",
>   line 35, in 
>       from object_detection.models import faster_rcnn_inception_resnet_v2_feature_extractor as frcnn_inc_res
>   File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/object_detection/models/faster_rcnn_inception_resnet_v2_feature_extractor.py",
>   line 28, in 
>       from nets import inception_resnet_v2 ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'nets'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change from

```
My\\ Drive
```

To just

```
My Drive
```

Because it is already in string quote.

Comment: Thank you so much @korakot Chaovavanich, I was making this noobish mistake for so many days. :P